# Is it possible to have table in table (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

Suppose I defined `music` as a table and gave it 3 columns: `album`, `artist`, and `track`:

```
CREATE TABLE music (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    album varchar(45) not null,
    artist varchar(30) not null, 
    track int(8)
);
```

Now I want another table `releasedy` which contains a column:

```
'Year' and the table music
```

I suppose for that I have to bind some row from table `music` with `year` from table `releasedy` in another table.  So I can know which year contains which musics.  If I'm not wrong I have to do that with foreign key.  How should I proceed?

Comment: Why not just have a column `year` in your `music` table? What good would you get from a separate table?

Comment: Like Anders suggests, it would make more sense to have a 'year' column in your music table. If you wanted to find all music released in a specific year then you could just use SELECT * FROM music WHERE year = 2013 (or whichever year you were looking for)

Comment: that was just an example to understand whether am  i able to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want "a table in a table", instead you want to match records from one table with records from another table in a query. You can create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html) on top of this query and use the view later as it if were a regular table.

As you guessed, establish a [foreign key relationship](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), then [JOIN the two tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is no "table in a table", only tables and relations between them.

> Table **releasedy** will have 2 columns, musicId & year. musicId is the foreign key to your music table.
>
> Join (as you called bind) these two:

```
SELECT * 
FROM music m
INNER JOIN releasedy r ON m.id = r.musicId
WHERE year = ..
```

Which is all overkill in this example but it illustrates the "binding" you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Functions { 
    public function getRows($sql){ 
         $result = mysql_query($sql); 
         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
               $data[] = $row; 
         } 
         return $data; 
    } 

    public function getMusicData(){ 
         $data = $this->getRows("SELECT * FROM music"); 
         return base64_encode(serialize($data)); 
    } 
} 

$func = new Functions(); 
$music = $func->getMusicData(); 
$sql = "insert into releasedy (id,Year) values (NULL,'".$music."')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

$id = 'your necessary id'; $read = "select * from releasedy where id = ".(int)$id; $data = mysql_query($read); $musics = unserialize(base64_decode($data['Year'])); foreach($musics as $music){ // do something }

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why your code works.

Comment: $id = 'your necessary id'; $read = "select * from releasedy where id = ".(int)$id; $data = mysql_query($read); $musics = unserialize(base64_decode($data['Year'])); foreach($musics as $music){ // do something }